# Recycler View Item Row color change alternatively

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have an issue, I want to have the recycler item row color alternatively. ie, If 1st row is in white color, 2nd row is in grey color and 3rd row is again white and 4th is again grey and so on. I tried one code, but it didn't work. Kindly help.

This is my code,

```
class ItemAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.DateViewHolder>() {

    private var ItemList: MutableList<Items>? = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var ItemViewModel: ItemRowListBinding
    private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

    init {
        this.ItemList = arrayListOf()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DateViewHolder {
        ItemViewModel = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.item_row_list,
            parent, false
        )
        return DateViewHolder(ItemViewModel)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DateViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if(position % 2 == 0) {                           
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.White);
        } else {
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Grey);
        }

        holder.bindItemDetail(ItemList!![position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ItemList!!.size
    }

    fun setItemList(scanList: MutableList<Items>) {
        this.ItemList = scanList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    inner class DateViewHolder(private var itemRowBinding: ItemRowListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemRowBinding.root) {

        fun bindItemDetail(ItemResponse: Items) {

            if (itemRowBinding.ItemDetailViewModel == null) {
                itemRowBinding.ItemDetailViewModel =
                    ItemDetailViewModel(
                        ItemResponse,
                        itemView.context
                    )
            } else {
                itemRowBinding.ItemDetailViewModel!!.setDetail(ItemResponse)
                itemRowBinding.executePendingBindings()
            }

            itemRowBinding.root.Detail.setOnClickListener {
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            itemRowBinding.root.itemLookup.setOnClickListener {
                Log.v(
                    "Clicked_ADAPTER",
                    "Clicked itemLookup adapter :: position -> $adapterPosition"
                )
            }

    }
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [setBackgroundDrawable's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)), it expects a `Drawable` resource ID, or `0` to clear the background. A `Color` is not a `Drawable`. So you probably want to use this:

```kotlin
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white))
```

Comment: You can get `context` by doing `holder.itemView.context` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the drawable you can use [setBackgroundResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int))

Here you are trying to give color in setBackgroundResouce so it is not giving the result

You can set background color using [setBackgroundColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundColor(int))

```
if(position % 2 == 0) {                           
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.White));
        } else {
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.Grey));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
It worked for me.

```
 if(position % 2 == 0){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(#A6A2A2);
    }else{
        holder.itemview.setBackgroundColor(#FFFFFF);
    }
```